# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error when accessing website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I have just uploaded an ASP.NET Core 2.1 app. I get this error when I try to run my website on IIS 8.0

> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module       IIS Web Core
>
> Notification BeginRequest
>
> Handler      Not yet determined
>
> Error Code       0x8007052e
>
> Config Error     Can not log on locally to
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\website-domain.my\dev.website-domain.my\MSS as user
>   username with virtual directory password
>
> Config File
>
> \?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\dev.website-domain.my(domain)(4.0)(pool)\dev.website-domain.my(domain)(4.0)(pool).config
>
> Requested URL    http://dev.website-domain.my:80/MSS/
>
> Physical Path
>
> C:\Inetpub\vhosts\website-domain.my\dev.website-domain.my\MSS\
>
> Logon Method Not yet determined
>   Logon User Not yet determined

Config Source:

```
<application path="/MSS" applicationPool="dev.website-domain.my(domain)(4.0)(pool)">  
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\website-domain.my\dev.website-domain.my\MSS" userName="username" password="[enc:AesProvider:4+kg/83a+hodVa/zMgLvRNQjrQjQp82oK77jfYDH0ak=:enc]" />           
</application>
```

I have given full access control to my username user on the MSS folder but i still get this error. My application pool is showing the username user in the Identity column as well. What else am I missing? Could this be a .net core issue also?

Comment: The error message "Can not log on locally" is clear enough. This user account cannot be used. Why do you need to use such a user account while the files are on drive C? Isn't the application pool identity enough?

Comment: I am unsure as well. I switched it back to application pool identity and the results are still the same.

Comment: “The results are still the same”? Edit your question to include the exact error when you switched back to application pool identity.

Answer (score 0):

I got I similar error when was deploying my ASP.NET Core app to IIS. The error was caused by missing IIS module AspNetCoreModuleV2.

It was fixed by installing ASP.NET Core 6.0 Runtime - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.5-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

My **web.config** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\DevOpsTestService2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

**The error I got**

[image]